# Do I need to use my reseller domain when writing apps that use the Reseller API?

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I am a Google Apps reseller and would like to use Google APIs like the [Google Apps Reseller API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/) to automate my reseller activities.

When I signed up to be a Google Apps reseller I was given a new Google Apps domain (reseller.mydomain.com).  If I want to automate reseller tasks using the Reseller API, do I have to logon to the Google Developer console as myuser@reseller.mydomain.com or can I continue to use myuser@mydomain.com?  I'm hoping I can use my normal user since that is where all my other Google development projects reside.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test your code using the sandbox with any Google Apps account. The only difference with the sandbox is the URLs use v1sandbox as opposed to v1 for the production API (which, yes requires you to use a reseller account). Give it a try in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/reseller/v1sandbox/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your active reseller account to access the Reseller API rather than your normal account.