# Does G Suite has sandbox or test account for testing of reseller API

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-reseller-api

I would like to use G Suite Reseller API to sell G Suite, now I am doing technical evaluation. Does Google provide sandbox or test account to partner for code development and test? How can I apply a sandbox or reseller test account?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the `v1sandbox` rather than `v1` (production url) as stated in this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26938654/5995040). I haven't tried to test this but in case it didn't work, try contacting the support regarding this issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Really appreciate your response. I'll try "v1sandbox" and hope it is workable.