# G-Suite Reseller Sandbox

Tags: php, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-reseller-api

I'm trying to integrate a WooCommerce store, to allow our customers to easily purchase new subscriptions in the g-suit environment. So far I have been using the following, for all information regarding the g-suit enviroment:

- https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/reseller/m/reseller/v1/reseller.subscriptions.list?_h=1&
- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/

and the following php-lib:

- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/quickstart/php

Everything working great so far, and I can fetch all our current subscriptions and other information - but, I'm now at a point where, I need to "`purchase/update`" subscriptions in the g-suite environment. Is their a test environment for this? I would love not to have to spend money to actually test my functionality :).

I have been looking around, and seem not to be able to find anything - regarding a sandbox environment.

Comment: Try to use `v1sandbox` instead of `v1` for production API which requires to use reseller account as stated from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922052/do-i-need-to-use-my-reseller-domain-when-writing-apps-that-use-the-reseller-api/26938654#26938654).
Please see the [Reseller API Prerequisites documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/prerequisites) for more infos.

Comment: and where do i set t his v1sandbox in my g suite resller php lib?